# converting string into multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

I'd like to 
convert this string:

```
$credit_packages_string = "300,0.25|1000,0.24|3000,0.22|4000,0.20|5000,0.18|6000,0.16|7000,0.14";
```

into this array:

```
 $credit_packages = array(  array( 'credit_amount'=> 300,
      'price_per_credit'=>0.25),
      array( 'credit_amount'=> 1000,
      'price_per_credit'=>0.24),
      array( 'credit_amount'=> 3000,
      'price_per_credit'=>0.22),
      array( 'credit_amount'=> 4000,
      'price_per_credit'=>0.20),
      array( 'credit_amount'=> 5000,
      'price_per_credit'=>0.18),
      array( 'credit_amount'=> 6000,
      'price_per_credit'=>0.16),
      array( 'credit_amount'=> 7000,
      'price_per_credit'=>0.14)
      );
```

how would you do it in a most efficient way?

Comment: There have been **7** views and **4** answers as of now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without using regular expression you'll need some loops so using a regex may be best

```
$credit_packages_string = "300,0.25|1000,0.24|3000,0.22|4000,0.20|5000,0.18|6000,0.16|7000,0.14";
preg_match_all( '~(?P<credit_amount>\d+),(?P<price_per_credit>[\d\.]+)~', $credit_packages_string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER );
print_r($matches);
```

[Link to code](http://ideone.com/4DsBf)

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) as;

```
$result = array();
$credits = explode('|',$credit_packages_string);
foreach($credits as $credit) {
        $credit_part = explode(',',$credit);
        $result[] = array('credit_amount'    => $credit_part[0],
                          'price_per_credit' => $credit_part[1]);
}
```

[**Working link**](http://www.ideone.com/Ldy0g)

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = explode(',', explode('|', $credit_packages_string));
```

This would only give you a numerical array. If you really want the 'credit_amount' and 'price_per_credit' keys, add the following:

```
foreach($i as &$array) {
    $i['credit_amount'] = $i[0];
    $i['price_per_credit'] = $i[1];
}
```