# convert string to 2D array using php

Tags: php

suppose I have a string like the follwing:

```
   01,03,02,15|05,04,06,10|07,09,08,11|12,14,13,16
```

How to convert it to a 2D array like the follwing using php?:

```
   01 03 02 15
   05 04 06 10 
   07 09 08 11  
   12 14 13 16
```

any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: i think the post is similar to

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898998/converting-string-into-multidimensional-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$tmp  = explode( '|', $str );
$data = array();

foreach ( $tmp as $k => $v )
{
  $data[] = explode( ',', $v );
}
```

[explode()](http://www.php.net/explode) is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = '01,03,02,15|05,04,06,10|07,09,08,11|12,14,13,16';
$arr = array_map(function($val) { return explode(',',$val); },explode('|',$str));

var_dump($arr);
```

PHP >= 5.3.0

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quickie option, which requires PHP 5.3.0 or above (that you should be using anyway).

```
$string = '01,03,02,15|05,04,06,10|07,09,08,11|12,14,13,16';
$array  = array_map('str_getcsv', explode('|', $string));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr1 = explode("|",$yourString);
$arr2 = array();
for ($i=0;$i<count($arr1);$i++)
    $arr2[] = explode(",",$arr1[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "01,03,02,15|05,04,06,10|07,09,08,11|12,14,13,16 ";
$array = explode('|', $str);
$final_array = array();
foreach($array as $val)
{
    array_push($final_array, explode(',', $val));
}
```