# convert string to predefined 2D array

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [convert string to 2D array using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785815/convert-string-to-2d-array-using-php)

I have the string like the following:

```
01,03,02,15|05,04,06,10|07,09,08,11|12,14,13,16
```

how can I convert the above string to a defined array like the one below:

```
$a[0] = array('column' => array("row1" => "01", "row2"=> "05", "row3" => "07", "row4" =>"12"));
$a[1] = array('column' => array("row1" => "03", "row2"=> "04", "row3" => "09", "row4" =>"14"));
$a[2] = array('column' => array("row1" => "02", "row2"=> "06", "row3" => "08", "row4" =>"13"));
$a[3] = array('column' => array("row1" => "15", "row2"=> "10", "row3" => "11", "row4" =>"16"));
```

I know I should use explode function but not sure how exactly it should be implemented for this, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: In the future, just update your existing question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
<?php

$a = array();
$str = "01,03,02,15|05,04,06,10|07,09,08,11|12,14,13,16";

$arr = explode("|", $str);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {

    $a[$i] = array('column' => array());

}

for ($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++) {

    $arr2 = explode(",", $arr[$i]);

    for ($j = 0; $j < count($arr2); $j++) {

        $key = "row" . intval($i + 1);
        $a[$j]['column'][$key] = $arr2[$j];

    }

}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($a);

?>
```

Answer (score 4):

With that format you basically just need:

```
$a = array_map("str_getcsv", explode("|", $string));
```

That gives you an enumerated array. If you want your specific named keys, then you have'd to post-process this structure again:

```
foreach ($a as $i=>$row) {
    $a[$i] = array("column" => array("row1"=>$row[0], "row2"=>$row[1], "row3"=>$row[2], "row4"=>$row[3]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sequence = "01,03,02,15|05,04,06,10|07,09,08,11|12,14,13,16";
$columns = explode("|", $sequence);

$result = array();

foreach ($columns as $i => $column)
{
    $rows = explode(",", $column);
    $sub_array = array();
    foreach ($rows as $id => $row)
    {
        $sub_array["row".($id+1)] = $row;
    }
    $result[$i] = array('column' => $sub_array);
}
```

Comment: the = array(); initializations aren't needed, but I keep writing them down :)
actually in the second case you somehow need to reset the variable like ($sub_array = array();), because it's scope doesn't end after one loop